# How to start nuxt.js on plesk?

Tags: node.js, plesk, nuxt.js

I'm trying to start a nuxt.js project on Plesk. Plesk need a *Application Startup File*, but nuxt.js have no index file.

[image: Application Startup File]
How can I start the server? Do I have to create a `server.js` and in this file execute `npm run start`?

Comment: Haven’t done that before, but there is an index.js in the build folder, isn’t it? Can check it later.

Comment: thanks for your post. There is no .js in the folder. I tried `node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt-start` as *Application Startup File* and it worked! Later I answer on my question.

Answer (score 3):

Need to install ***nuxt-start*** module

> npm i --save nuxt-start

in Application Startup File

> node_modules/nuxt-start/bin/nuxt-start.js

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

In the field *Application Startup File* you have to put `node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt-start`.

Comment: In this case I just get "It works" response instead of the actual app

Answer (score 0):

Click run script button
and
type start and close page if you want to restart again and show running process.
Type this:

```
pgrep -f npm
```

And then kill that process:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```